# Sending Emails using SMTP Gmail Codeigniter work local but gives error on the host

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, codeigniter-3, shared-hosting

I am using email class in Codeigniter to send email throw Gmail smtp 
Here is my setting for this:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'email@gmail.com';   // I write my correct email here
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';         // I write my correct password here
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = "tls";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'My Name');
$this->email->to('another_mail@server.com'); // I write onther email here
$this->email->subject('test gmail smtp');
$this->email->message('success :)');
if (!$this->email->send()) {
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

I have tried it on my local machine the code works fine and all of the emails have been received.
After I have uploaded my script to my GoDaddy host it gives me this warning:-

> fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587
>   (Connection timed out)

and email `print_debugger();` print this error:-

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.

And I have tried this code on another host (Bluehost) it gives me the same warning and error.

Any one know where I go wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled the `allowing less secure app` on gmail? the reason is google need to verify if you are actually allowing this type of actions so i believe configuring it will resolve your issue. - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @KaoriYui That wouldn't result in a Connection timed out error but rather a Auth-error.

Comment: Yes, I have. and it is working on my localhost

Comment: You should check with GoDaddy. They are famous for blocking outgoing SMTP connections that doesn't go through their SMTP relay,

Comment: I have uploaded it on bluehost website and it gives me same error

Comment: Nothing says that other hosting companies can't have a similar setup. If it works on localhost, then you know that your code is ok. If it doesn't work on a hosted server, you should contact them and ask, since it's probably some setting you need there, if it is allowed at all. I'm guessing it's a shared hosting? (web hotel and not a VPS?). Those are often much more limited.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes it is shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

Port 587 is blocked by go daddy for outgoing smtp connections, use one of the following ports according to your requirement as specified.

non SSL - 80, 3535, 25

SSL - 465

https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-do-i-do-if-i-have-trouble-connecting-to-my-email-account-319

Comment: Thank you for your response but it changed the error number to 111 here is the error
 The following SMTP error was encountered: 111 Connection refused
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: did you try port 25 ?

Answer (score 0):

check php.ini file on production server.
If you have `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini change it to `extension=php_openssl.dll` (remove coma, and restart apache or nginx).

Comment: I am on shared host so I cannot view php.ini file and make changes on it :(

Comment: You can contact with your provider, and ask them to make chnages.